# Copy content of Word range to variable for later use?

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, range, reusability

I have a Word document that has a checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked (unchecked) I select a range, copy it into a Range variable and then delete the original range. If the checkbox is clicked again (checked) I need to put the range stored in the variable back in its original position with the formatted text that was deleted. The idea here is that a user can decide if he wants a range of text visible or not.

The issue I have is that the range variable (where I store the original range) contains only a pointer to this original range and when I delete it the pointer is now pointing to nothing, hence the variable holds nothing.

I've tried passing the range to another variable byVal, pasting the original range to another word document and then copying it from there (text remains in the new document but the original memory location is swiped so still pointing to nothing!). **Any ideas on how I can keep the original range for reuse on a later time?**

Also, I am deleting the range because if I only hide the text I have empty spaces left which don't look nice.

Comment: You can only reference an *existing* Range, so it needs to be in a document somewhere.  You can't store a Range entirely in memory (unless maybe you managed to store all of its properties separately so you could reconstruct it when needed)

Comment: You can set a range to invisible with `range.Font.Hidden = True`. Maybe that's a better alternative. You can make it visible again by setting `.Font.Hidden = False` (I have no empty spaces left).

Comment: To understand what a `Range` is see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range)

Comment: I agree with TimWilliams, FunThomas and TimothyRylatt - among other things, a range has a context (e.g. some formatting, as a minimum) that you might or might not want to paste later on.

You could try copying the xml in yourrange.WordOpenXml and using someotherrange.InsertXML to insert it, but I wouldn't want to rely on it.